# Usefulness of GraphQL

Tags: django, reactjs, graphql

I am relatively new to learning Graphql. I am working with another developer who is designing the front end in ReactJS and backend in Django. His opinion regarding Graphql is that it is not necessary and can use MySql and Django ORM instead. I am not sure what benefit then Graphql brings if entire development can be done using only ReactJS, DjangoORM and MySql.

Comment: This is really an opinion based question I think.  For your project GraphQL might not be helpful or useful.  As for benefits and such, you can get on Google and see what companies use GraphQL and the benefits of the technology.

Comment: The main advantage of GraphQL, in my opinion, is to avoid over-fetching. I work with REST API's, and it is very common for people to fetch big blobs of data. If the unnecessary load in the network isn't enough, people often just save the over-fetched data in the application state--not only wasting the users memory, but also making it harder to maintain the application as the state gets unnecessarily huge. This is very personal and people will often choose technologies they are more familiar with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing a standard API you can make a design like this to get a list of users:

```
[
  {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    age: '',
    address: {
      street: '',
      neighbourhood: '',
      number: ''
    }
  },
  .... more results with the same structure
]
```

in this case if you want to show only the user *name* and *email* getting *address* and *age* is not worth it and is a waste of resources take in mind that this is just a simple example in some cases you are going to deal with many fields.

With GraphQL you can ask and get just the information you need so you can ask just for one field and that's all you are going to get.

Comment: "standard API", That looks more like REST, there is no standard API, at best you can tell that REST is industry standard API architecture.

Answer (score 6):

#### ReactJS is a frontend framework.

#### DjangoORM is an ORM, MySQL is a database.

#### GraphQL is an API architecture.

None of which can be compared to another one.

You can't use DjangoORM and MySQL instead of GraphQL, at best you can use GraphQL instead of REST, which both are architectural types for API's.

The difference, as simple as I can put it:

GraphQL architectured APIs give you exactly what you want from the server. (roughly)
REST architectured APIs give you standard schemes for the given objects. (roughly)